# From superoperator of unitary to the unitary itself

Tags: linear-algebra, quantum-mechanics

I have a question about super operators. Let's say I have the super operator of some unitary matrix $u$ called $SU$ where $SU = u^\ast\otimes u$ (here $u^\ast$ is the complex conjugate of $u$). If I have $SU$, how can I get $u$ from this? Is there any tensor product relation I can use?

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand\SU{\text{SU}}$Vectorizing the matrix $u$ (by writing $a_i:=u_{k,l}$ for $i:=(k,l)$, so that the entries of the matrix $u^*\otimes u$ are $\bar u_{k,l}u_{r,s}=\bar a_i a_j$ for $i:=(k,l)$ and $j:=(r,s)$), we reduce the problem to the following:

> For a nonzero complex vector $a=(a_i)$, we know the matrix $p=(p_{ij})$, where $p_{ij}=\bar a_i a_j$. Can we recover $a$ based on this information?

To answer this question, note that the condition that $a$ is nonzero implies that $a_i\ne0$ for some $i$. Fix any such $i$.

Then $p_{ii}=\bar a_i a_i=|a_i|^2\ne0$, and from the condition $p_{ij}=\bar a_i a_j$ we get $a_j=C_{ij}a_i$, where $C_{ij}:=p_{ij}/p_{ii}$ is a known complex number.

It also follows that $a_i=\sqrt{p_{ii}} e^{it}$ for some $t\in[0,2\pi)$ and hence
$$a_j=C_{ij}\sqrt{p_{ii}} e^{it}=\frac{p_{ij}}{\sqrt{p_{ii}}}\,e^{it}.$$
for all $j$.

Thus, we have determined all the $a_j$'s up to the constant factor $e^{it}$ of modulus $1$.

> Thus, we have determined the matrix $u$ up to the constant factor $e^{it}$ of modulus $1$:
> $$u_{r,s}=\frac{p_{(k,l)(r,s)}}{\sqrt{p_{(k,l)(k,l)}}}\,e^{it}$$
> for some $(k,l)$ such that $p_{(k,l)(k,l)}>0$ and for all $(r,s)$, where $p:=\SU$.

This is all that can be done: the matrix $u$ can be determined only up to a constant factor $e^{it}$ of modulus $1$. Indeed, if $u$ is a unitary matrix such that $u^*\otimes u$ is the given matrix $\SU$, then for any real $t$ we have that $v:=e^{it}u$ is a unitary matrix such that $v^*\otimes v=\SU$. $\quad\Box$

---

At the [OP's request](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/456277/from-superoperator-of-unitary-to-the-unitary-itself/456287#comment1181729_456287), here is the link to a [pdf image](https://u.pcloud.link/publink/show?code=XZKVWiVZD4HF0SYhDmbpNcizMd4N5zELDsdk) (two pages) of a Mathematica notebook providing an example showing how to get $u$ from $\SU$, up to a constant factor of modulus $1$.

Comment: sorry i dont understand how this is related to the question i asked.

Comment: @MushahidKhan : I have added a detail (about the vectorizing) in the beginning of the answer. Do you still not understand it? If so, let me know the first place in the answer that you do not understand.

Comment: @MushahidKhan : I have also simplified the answer.

Comment: Can you show this with an example? I think that would help me understand :)

Comment: @MushahidKhan : Example of what?

Comment: An example of a matrix SU from which we can get u

Comment: @MushahidKhan : I have added a link to such an example.

Comment: @MushahidKhan : Do you have a further response to this answer?